# Opening the second Wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class (CoreClient.cs) managing all the program, and my program has many wpf windows to open not simultaneously.
When CoreClient tries to open the first window (Config.xaml) asking for configuration's data, everything is fine!!
When CoreClient tries to open a second window i receive an error. (Login.xaml) This should be the login window, i've tried with other window and i receive always the same error. The impression is that i can't open any window after the first for some reason.

Any idea?

CoreClient.cs

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using MioEngine;

namespace Client
{
    private EventWaitHandle _wait= new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

    public class CoreClient
    {
      //[...]
      var _config = new Configuration(_wait);
      Application.Current.Run(_config);
      _wait.WaitOne();
      //some data from _config is taken when _config close...
      var _login = new Login(_mySocket, _wait);
      Application.Current.Run(_login);
      _wait.WaitOne();
      //[...]
    }
}
```

Config.xaml

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Configuration: Window
    {
        private EventWaitHandle _wait;

        public Configuration(EventWaitHandle wait)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _wait = wait;
            //
        }

        private void bExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //takes parameters from many textbox
            wait.Set();            
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Login.xaml

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using MyEngine;
using MyPack;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Login: Window
    {
        public Login(MySocket socket, EventWaitHandle wait)
        {
            InitializeComponent();   //<------ InvalidOperationException
            _wait = wait;
            //some code...
        }

        private void bExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
            //Control and setup the network and makes the LOGIN 
            wait.Set();       
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Keeping on trying I've discovered that if I made all this run FROM a WPF window, it's all ok (but i must create a parent window unusefull for me).

Tried also Show and ShowDialog having some issues:
With Show I've no exceptions but my second window isn't shown (using EventWaitHandle)
Tith ShowDialog my CoreClient remains in loop or waiting for something after the launch of the second window

Comment: Can you tell what is the error you're getting?

Comment: **InvalidOperationException** on **InitializeComponent();**

Comment: can you show the code that you are using to open both windows, also is this in CodeBehind or MVVM

Comment: Post some relevant code. Of specific interest is the constructor for Login.xaml (Login.cs) and what it's trying to do.

Comment: Show how you are trying to open the window

Comment: {
 var _config = new Configuration();

 ...some data from _config is taken when _config close...

 var _login = new Login(_mySocket);

}

Comment: @IllidanMalar - Please edit your original post and add the code there (using code tags).

Comment: Does it error out if you run the Login Form first instead of the config form. Also put a breakpoint on your login forms IntializeComponent method and step through it to determine what component is causing the error.

Comment: Is always the second window to generate the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it
But I have to use a UserControl or Page (not Window) for any secondary windows
But they look and behave like a Window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationWindow navWin = new NavigationWindow();
        navWin.Content = new UserControl1();
        navWin.ShowsNavigationUI = false;
        navWin.Show();
    }
}
```