# Open a WPF Application multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to run my Programm multiple times at the same time, but I can open it only ones. When I try to open it the second time nothing happen.
The Programm is written in C# with WPF and compiled in Visual Studio Community 2017. Is there a option to set this up?

Comment: Do you multiple debug instances or just open the program?

Comment: Try to double-click on the .exe in the output folder, which should be something like `c:\{YourProjectFolder}\bin\Debug`. This should spin up a new process.

Comment: just open the programm from the output Folder

Comment: also you can create the object of class and object.Show() will open a new instance of your window ! create as many instances you want to open multiple windows ! `WindwA winObj = new WinA();  winObj.Show()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationWindow navWin = new NavigationWindow();
        navWin.Content = new UserControl1();
        navWin.ShowsNavigationUI = false;
        navWin.Show();
    }
}
```

Credits: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430457/opening-the-second-wpf-window)